# WebApi controller accessing its StatelessService instance

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-service-fabric

I am hosting WebApi controller inside a stateless service with one instance. The service instance (I mean the instance of the WebApiService class created by the SF runtime) maintains some transient state as member fields, exposing the state through internal (thread-safe) methods. The WebApi controller needs to call the methods to access that state.

```
WebApiService.cs:
-----------------
internal sealed class WebApiService : StatelessService
{
  private int _state;

  internal int GetState() { return this._state; }

ServiceController.cs:
---------------------
public class ServiceController : ApiController
{
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStateAsync()
  {
    // Here I'd like to grab somehow the WebApiService instance 
    // and call its GetState internal method.
```

My questions are:

1. How can the controller get a reference to the WebApiService instance?
2. Is it safe to store the WebApiService instance in a static field (perhaps set in the WebAspiService constructor)?

Comment: so, let me get this right: you're implementing state in a stateless service?

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing some transient in-memory state in a stateless service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the service instance as a dependency to your controllers through a DI container.

Here's an example with Web API hosted on Katana using Unity. It's a stateful service but it works exactly the same way for a stateless service: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/Services/WordCount/WordCount.Service

Here's an example using Asp.Net Core and its built-in dependency injection container (also stateful, but same thing applies): https://github.com/vturecek/service-fabric-xray/tree/master/src/xray.Data

Comment: I have chosen the DI route you recommended using Autofac. Works like a charm, thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a DI container for that. I can recommend [simpleinjector](https://simpleinjector.org/) (but there are many that can do the same), simpleinjector has got object lifetime management also per request and a web api package. You could put your state instance in a container as a singleton and inject it in your controllers, that would be a thread safe way, better stay away from static fields in a multithreaded web environment.

Comment: Thanks, you say basically the same as the accepted answer above, which I have chosen because of the links to the samples. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer and especally for mentioning the threading issues...

Answer (score 0):

You have to resolve the stateless service in your controller before you can call the methods of the stateless service:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetStateAsync()
{
     var proxyLocation = new ServiceUriBuilder("WebApiService");
     var svc = ServiceProxy.Create<IWebApiService>(proxyLocation.ToUri());
     return svc.GetState();
}
```

You need to create an interface IWebApiService that contains the GetState method. WebApiService needs to implement it. Basically you need to abstract WebApiService with the IWebApiService interface.

Comment: I definitely don't recommend doing this. This is meant for cross-service remote procedure call. What this will end up doing is opening a network channel back to the service instance, which means every time you call a method on it, it will serialize the call, send it all the way down the remoting stack, deserialize, call the method, serialize the results, go back down the remoting stack, and finally deserialize.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @VaclavTurecek! For cross-service remote procedure calls, is it also possible to inject (via DI) the dependencies (stateless services)?

Comment: You can use ServiceProxy to create a proxy instance (which takes the form of the target service interface) and inject that directly into your service instance. Benefit here is that your service is working against the interface of the target service whose methods you want to call. However, this only works if the target service is not partitioned, because you specify the partition key when you create the proxy. Therefore, a slightly better approach is to inject an IServiceProxyFactory and use that in your service to create proxies (it can also be mocked for unit testing).